# Is this json api is correct or not?

Tags: android, kotlin

Is it below api is correct or not? If it is correct then it is not showing "data" jsonObject . When i use response.body(). It is only showing me {"message": "success"} but other data is not showing.

I try it showing many time but always it is showing {"message": "success"}.

Please help me

thanks in advance

My Kotlin code here with retrofit

```
 service.addressSendToServer(addressModel, token)
            .enqueue(object : Callback<AddressSaveListModel> {
                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<AddressSaveListModel>,
                    response: Response<AddressSaveListModel>
                ) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        addressSaveListModel.setMessage(response.body()?.getMessage()!!)
                        addressSaveListModel = response.body()!!
                        Log.e("TAG", "response 33: " + Gson().toJson(response.body()))

                        Log.i("SaveDataat",""+response.body()?.getSaveDataAddress()?.getEmail())
   override fun onFailure(call: Call<AddressSaveListModel>, t: Throwable) {
                    Log.d("Repository", "Failed:::" + t.cause + ":" + t.message)
                }
            })





{
"message": "success",
"data": {
    "login_mode": "gm",
    "device": [
        "Android"
    ],
    "_id": "5d96f113eb184f3ff4da1a2f",
    "contact_number": "8755529143",
    "email": "sundarsharma2018@gmail.com",
    "fcm": "8ZJDx26g39bXtxLkbwOXYy0F1HJ2",
    "profile_address": [
        {
            "_id": "5d96f113eb184f3ff4da1a30",
            "address": "Spring House, C28C, LG Flr, Archohm Bldg, C Block, Sector 8, Noida, Uttar Pradesh 201301, India",
            "lat": 28.5942446,
            "lng": 77.3262771,
            "locality": "Noida"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5d971b30eb184f3ff4da1a31",
            "address": "noida",
            "lat": 23,
            "lng": 78,
            "locality": "noida"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5d971c4feb184f3ff4da1a32",
            "address": "noida",
            "lat": 23.565656,
            "lng": 78.566565,
            "locality": "noida"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5d97a5c3346f755cbe2bf41c",
            "address": "noida",
            "lat": 23.565656,
            "lng": 78.566565,
            "locality": "noida"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5d98228b346f755cbe2bf434",
            "address": "noida",
            "lat": 23.565656,
            "lng": 78.566565,
            "locality": "noida"
        }
    ],
    "username": "Your Tutor",
    "__v": 0,
    "otp": 1725,
    "createdAt": "2019-10-05T04:56:43.945Z"
}
}
```

This is my model class

```
class AddressSaveListModel()  {

@SerializedName("data")
private var dataAddress: DataSaveAddess? = null

@SerializedName("message")
private var message: String? = null



fun getMessage(): String? {
    return message
}

fun setMessage(message: String) {
    this.message = message
}

fun getSaveDataAddress(): DataSaveAddess? {
    return dataAddress
}

fun setSaveDataAddress(dataAddress: DataSaveAddess) {
    this.dataAddress = dataAddress
}
}

class DataSaveAddess {
@SerializedName("login_mode")
private var login_mode: String? = null
@SerializedName("device")
private var device: List<String>? = null
@SerializedName("username")
private var username: String? = null
@SerializedName("email")
private var email: String? = null
@SerializedName("contact_number")
private var contact_number: String? = null
@SerializedName("fcm")
private var fcm: String? = null
@SerializedName("profile_address")
private var profileAddress: List<ProfileAddressSave>? = null
@SerializedName("otp")
private var otp: Int? = null
@SerializedName("_id")
private var id: String? = null



fun getLoginMode(): String? {
    return login_mode
}

fun setLoginMode(login_mode: String) {
    this.login_mode= login_mode
}


fun getDevice(): List<String>? {
    return device
}

fun setDevice(device: List<String>) {
    this.device = device
}

fun getEmail(): String? {
    return email
}

fun setEmail(email: String) {
    this.email= email
}

fun getUsername(): String? {
    return username
}

fun setUsername(username: String) {
    this.username = username
}



fun getContactNumber(): String? {
    return contact_number
}

fun setContactNumber(contact_number: String) {
    this.contact_number = contact_number
}


fun getFcm(): String? {
    return fcm
}

fun setFcm(fcm: String) {
    this.fcm = fcm
}


fun getProfileAddress(): List<ProfileAddressSave>?{
    return profileAddress;
}


fun setProfileAddress(profileAddress: List<ProfileAddressSave>){
    this.profileAddress= profileAddress;
}


fun getOtp(): Int? {
    return otp
}

fun setOtp(otp: Int) {
    this.otp= otp
}


fun getId(): String? {
    return id
}

fun setId(id: String) {
    this.id = id
}


}

class ProfileAddressSave() {


@SerializedName("address")
private var address: String? = null
@SerializedName("locality")
private var locality: String? = null
@SerializedName("lat")
private var lat: Double? = null
@SerializedName("lng")
private var lng: Double? = null
@SerializedName("_id")
private var addressperlistId: String? = null




fun getAddress(): String? {
    return address
}

fun setAddress(address: String) {
    this.address= address
}



fun getLocality(): String? {
    return locality
}

fun setLocality(locality: String) {
    this.locality= locality
}



fun getLong(): Double? {
    return lng
}

fun setLong(lng: Double) {
    this.lng= lng
}


fun getLat(): Double? {
    return lat
}

fun setLat(lat: Double) {
    this.lat= lat
}


fun getId(): String? {
    return addressperlistId
}

fun setId(addressperlistId: String) {
    this.addressperlistId= addressperlistId
}

override fun describeContents(): Int {
    return 0
}
```

}

Output:

```
2019-10-05 12:16:21.185 13296-13296/now.bike E/TAG: response 33:                      {"message":"success"}
2019-10-05 12:16:21.185 13296-13296/now.bike I/SaveDataat: null
2019-10-05 12:16:21.194 13296-13296/now.bike I/SaveDataat: success
2019-10-05 12:16:21.195 13296-13296/now.bike W/System.err:    org.json.JSONException: No value for data
2019-10-05 12:16:21.195 13296-13296/now.bike W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:392)
2019-10-05 12:16:21.195 13296-13296/now.bike W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:612)
2019-10-05 12:16:21.195 13296-13296/now.bike W/System.err:     at now.bike.repository.AddressRepository$insertPostAddresstoserver$1.onResponse(AddressRepository.kt:196)
2019-10-05 12:16:21.195 13296-13296/now.bike W/System.err:     at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
2019-10-05 12:16:21.195 13296-13296/now.bike W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
2019-10-05 12:16:21.195 13296-13296/now.bike W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
2019-10-05 12:16:21.195 13296-13296/now.bike W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
```

Comment: The json data is valid you can check it in [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com) to check valid json syntax. And can you post your code how you are parsing the JSONObject data?

Comment: @TobiburRahman Please check again i have uploaded code

Answer (score 0):

please try as below

```
service.addressSendToServer(addressModel, token)
            .enqueue(object : Callback<AddressSaveListModel> {
                override fun onResponse(
                        call: Call<AddressSaveListModel>,
                        response: Response<AddressSaveListModel>
                ) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {

                        val response_body =response.body()

                        Log.e("TAG", "response 33: " +Gson().toJson(response_body))
                        Log.e("TAG", "response data: " +Gson().toJson(response_body.getSaveDataAddress()))
                        Log.e("TAG", "response message: " +Gson().toJson(response_body .getMessage()))


                        override fun onFailure(call: Call<AddressSaveListModel>, t: Throwable) {
                            Log.d("Repository", "Failed:::" + t.cause + ":" + t.message)
                        }
                    })
```

Comment: Showing me below output         2019-10-05 13:59:53.465 21241-21241/now.bike E/TAG: response 33: {"message":"success"}
2019-10-05 13:59:53.466 21241-21241/now.bike E/TAG: response data: null
2019-10-05 13:59:53.466 21241-21241/now.bike E/TAG: response message: "success"

Comment: Log.e("TAG", "response 33: " +Gson().toJson(response_body)) it will show full response from server so check from serverside you are not getting response you shown in question @sundersharma

Comment: your full response shown in your question should come in response.body then only it can be get in response_body.getSaveDataAddress() @sundersharma

Comment: thanks sorry i can not give vote to you coz due to less point

Comment: np happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use these model classes:

```
data class AddressSaveListModel (

    @SerializedName("message") val message : String,
    @SerializedName("data") val data : Data
)
```

```
data class Data (

    @SerializedName("login_mode") val login_mode : String,
    @SerializedName("device") val device : List<String>,
    @SerializedName("_id") val _id : String,
    @SerializedName("contact_number") val contact_number : Int,
    @SerializedName("email") val email : String,
    @SerializedName("fcm") val fcm : String,
    @SerializedName("profile_address") val profile_address : List<Profile_address>,
    @SerializedName("username") val username : String,
    @SerializedName("__v") val __v : Int,
    @SerializedName("otp") val otp : Int,
    @SerializedName("createdAt") val createdAt : String
)
```

```
data class Profile_address (

    @SerializedName("_id") val _id : String,
    @SerializedName("address") val address : String,
    @SerializedName("lat") val lat : Double,
    @SerializedName("lng") val lng : Double,
    @SerializedName("locality") val locality : String
)
```

And try again. Its better to use kotlin data classes if you are using kotlin instead of getter setter functions. And also please check if the actual json "data" is not null.